# Aggregate and $or operator in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

This is my mongodb query:

```
Booking.aggregate([
  { $match:
    { $and: [
      { $or: [
          { isDoubleRoom },
          { chosenRoom }
        ]},
      { month },
      { year },
    ] }},
  { $group: { _id: "$fullDate", count: { $sum: 1 } } }
]
```

In a first stage I would like to filter out by month, year and conditionally: if isDoubleRoom then filter only by double rooms, if it is not then filter by chosenRoom property. The thing is that $or does not switch between filters. Query returns not filtered (by chosen isDoubleRoom $or chosenRoom) results. The same worked when I used it with `find` instead of `aggregate`. But here I need `aggregate` in order to count filtered results.

Comment: Can you post please sample documents with expected result?

Answer (score 0):

You should use [$cond](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/)

```
{
    $match: {
        $and: [
            {
                $cond: [{isDoubleRoomBool}, {isDoubleRoom} , {chosenRoom}] //
            },
            { month },
            { year },
        ]
    }
}
```